# deluxetable creates "floating s" in all tables

Tags: tables

I am using [deluxetable.sty](http://casa.colorado.edu/~danforth/comp/tex/deluxetable.sty) to create tables but it keeps creating a floating 's' (see image) and I can't figure out where it's coming from. It always occurs above the last row of the table data with no preference for column, but it does appear to be centered. I'm going to assume the style file is the culprit but I'm not familiar enough with the coding to parse through it.

[image: Floating 's' Image]

mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{deluxetable}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{deluxetable}{ccccccccccccc}
    \tabletypesize{\tiny}
    \rotate
    \tablecaption{Spectral Data for Selected Regions} \label{tbl:RegionData}
    \tablewidth{0pt}
    \tablehead
    {  
        \colhead{Region}             &
        \colhead{$N_H$}              &
        \colhead{$kT$ (Hard)}        &
        \colhead{$kT$ (Soft)}        &
        & & & & &
        \colhead{$\tau_u$ (Hard) }   &   
        \colhead{$\tau_u$ (Soft)}    &
        \colhead{$\chi^2_\nu$ (DOI)}  
    %   \vpsace{-0.1cm}
        \\

        \vspace{-0.3cm}
        & & & &
        \colhead{$Ne$}      &
        \colhead{$Mg$}      &
        \colhead{$Si$}      &
        \colhead{$S$}       &
        \colhead{$Fe = Ni$} & 
        & &     

        \\

        & \colhead{$\times 10^{22}$ $cm^{-2}$} 
        & \colhead{$keV$} 
        & \colhead{$keV$} 
        & & & & &
        & \colhead{$s \: cm^{-3}$}
        & \colhead{$s \: cm^{-3}$} &    
    }

    \startdata
        1  & $0.69^{+0.04}_{-0.04}$ & $0.66^{+0.09}_{-0.04}$ & $0.30^{+0.02}_{-0.03}$ & \nodata & $1.8^{+1.0}_{-0.1}$ & $1.5^{+0.2}_{-0.1}$  & $1.8^{+0.6}_{-0.5}$ & $2.0^{+0.2}_{-0.2}$ & $3.3^{+2.2}_{-1.1} \times 10^{11}$  & $1.4^{+2.9}_{-0.7} \times 10^{12}$ & 1.51 (372) \\
    \enddata    
    \vspace{-15pts}
    \tablecomments{My table comments. }
\end{deluxetable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\vspace{-15pt}`, not `\vspace{-15pts}`

Answer (score 3):

The dangling “s” is due to wrong syntax: you use

```
\vspace{-15pts}
```

where the correct call should be

```
\vspace{-15pt}
```

In this context, `pt` is a unit of measure symbol, just like “km” for “kilometers”, so it doesn't take a plural suffix.